# How to write a Google Sheets script function that identifies value depending on cell in the same row

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

How would I go about writing a custom function in Google Sheets that retrieves a value if the text in a cell in the same row equals what's identified in the function.
For example: If I have a bunch of values from a form, a function that'll allow me to identify the full range of where to look, the column that the number values are contained in, and the text I want the function to look for in the given range.

It's a bit confusing to just describe it. I'll make an example sheet and post it here.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into `MATCH`?

If I understand the question, you could do something like:

```
MATCH(A1, A2:A100, 1)
```

Where A1 is your key, A2:A100 is your range, and 1 is the search type.

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378

Comment: I looked into this a bit. What I'm trying to do is find a value depending on a different cell in the same row. So say I used this to find the text, I'd still need to pull the value from that row.

Comment: Ah, then `HLOOKUP` is what you're looking for.
`HLOOKUP(search_key, range, index, [is_sorted])`

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093375